# JQuery PrintArea + Bootstrap + ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap

Estoy usando ASP.NET + Bootstrap y quiero implementar un boton IMPRIMIR PANTALLA usando PrintArea.js y me sale como muestro en captura de pantalla.  (sin el formato tal como se muestra en mi formulario) y sin embargo si hago CONTROL P a la pagina me esta mostrando tal cual (dejo tambien en imagen) Alguien me podria decir por favor que mas debo hacer para que usando PrintArea me muestre tal cual esta mi pantalla real (con estilo)?

Gracias de Antemano!

P.D. Adjunto una captura de lo que me imprime el CTRL + P (con estilo tal como se muestra en en mi formmulario) y otra captura que me imprime el Jquery printArea sin estilo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnImprimirPantalla").click(function () {
                $("div#myPrintArea").printArea();
            })
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<a href="#" id="btnImprimirPantalla" class="btn btn-info btn-md" role="button">Imprimir Pantalla</a>

<div id="myPrintArea">
Y AQUI COLOCO MI CODIGO QUE QUIERO QUE SE MUESTRE EN LAIMPRESION
 </div>
```

Comment: Esto se debe a que no reconoce los estilos para esto debes de crear una hoja de estilos con el @media print, incluso creo que se puede agregando media="print" a las referencias de tus hojas de estilos aunque esto no me funciono a mi, hechale un ojo a esto: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Gracias. Eso no lo coonzco. Me podrías dar un ejemplo por favor de cómo debería ser? Yo utilizo el estilo del bootstrap mas una hoja de estilo propia las cuales las llamo desde  mi formulario aspx

Comment: Es un poco raro de explicar y no soy un experto totalmente pero vere la forma de explicar lo mas que se pueda, existe algun otro medio por el cual te pueda ayudar? Correo? Hangout? Si no, te lo comento aqui.

Comment: gmail. Mi usuario de stackoverflow está relacionado con e gmail. Clic en mi usuario. o Mi buzón es lizzy.mb@gmail.com Muchas gracias!

Comment: recuerden agregar la respuesta, así haremos crecer a la comunidad :D saludos

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que incluir una hoja de estilos exclusiva para la impresión, y en esta hoja de estilos definir los estilos que solo utilizaras en la vista de impresión:

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
</head>
```